# First capistrano deploy does't make any effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

how is it going? I have a Rails 4 app and I'm trying to deploy it with capistrano 3 on my server.

I already installed with `bundle install` and `cap install`, generating the files. I already added my info com deploy.rb file and when I run the command for the first deploy, it doesn't print the log on my console and do any effect.

```
usuario$ cap production deploy
usuario$
```

I ran this command with the `--trace` to see more details:

```
usuario$ cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:rvm:hook (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:test_which_passenger (first_time)
** Execute passenger:test_which_passenger
** Execute passenger:rvm:hook
** Execute rvm:hook
** Invoke rvm:check (first_time)
** Execute rvm:check
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:bundler:hook (first_time)
** Execute passenger:bundler:hook
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
** Execute git:check
** Invoke deploy:check:directories (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:directories
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:check:make_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:set_previous_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_previous_revision
** Invoke deploy:started (first_time)
** Execute deploy:started
** Invoke deploy:updating (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:new_release_path (first_time)
** Execute deploy:new_release_path
** Execute deploy:updating
** Invoke git:create_release (first_time)
** Invoke git:update (first_time)
** Invoke git:clone (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper 
** Execute git:clone
** Execute git:update
** Execute git:create_release
** Invoke deploy:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_current_revision
** Invoke git:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute git:set_current_revision
** Invoke deploy:symlink:shared (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:shared
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:updated (first_time)
** Invoke bundler:install (first_time)
** Execute bundler:install
** Execute deploy:updated
** Invoke deploy:compile_assets (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Execute deploy:compile_assets
** Invoke deploy:assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute deploy:assets:precompile
** Invoke deploy:assets:backup_manifest (first_time)
** Execute deploy:assets:backup_manifest
** Invoke deploy:cleanup_assets (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Execute deploy:cleanup_assets
** Invoke deploy:normalize_assets (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Execute deploy:normalize_assets
** Invoke deploy:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Execute deploy:migrate
** Invoke deploy:publishing (first_time)
** Execute deploy:publishing
** Invoke deploy:symlink:release (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:release
** Invoke deploy:restart (first_time)
** Execute deploy:restart
** Invoke passenger:restart (first_time)
** Execute passenger:restart
** Invoke deploy:published (first_time)
** Execute deploy:published
** Invoke deploy:finishing (first_time)
** Execute deploy:finishing
** Invoke deploy:cleanup (first_time)
** Execute deploy:cleanup
** Invoke deploy:finished (first_time)
** Execute deploy:finished
** Invoke deploy:log_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:log_revision
usuario$
```

...and anything was created on the server (current and release folder).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any clue.

EDIT

That is my deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, 'my_app_name'
set :repo_url, 'my_user@my_server_ip:/my_path_to/app_repo.git'

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app_name"
set :default_stage, "production"
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')

set :keep_releases, 3
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
```

Comment: What are the roles assigned to the production server?

Comment: I'll edit my answer...

Comment: take a look on my deploy.rb file

Comment: I have another project with the same config working fine... I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: the server is another droplet on digitalocean, maybe it's a server issue... but no errors is showing for me...

Comment: Can you post your `config/deploy/production.rb`?

Comment: This file is with the default data (generated by capistrano)

Comment: Hey man! Thanks! That was it! I forgot to config something on this file! Thanks!